# How i can add post views to author page?

Tags: wordpress, view, author

Sorry my english :)

my themes have views function.How i can add post page views to author page?

(without plugin)

my themes have views function already.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is it just me, or are we missing a lot of context here? What system, language and/or platform are you using and asking about?

Comment: Sorry.  System Wordpress :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself***a before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress themes for an author, you can edit your `author.php` file in your WordPress theme.

If you are storing the total post views in `wp_postmeta` table then you can count all the post views by `author id`.

I hope this will give you an idea.